# Unable to send Android Build

Tags: codenameone

I am getting a rather frustrating error when sending for Android build. Is the CN! cloud down or its from my end? See my full stack trace below.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version Unknown-0.0
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.checkRecordVersion(InputRecord.java:552)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:565)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:529)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$100(HttpURLConnection.java:91)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$8.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1298)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.uploadToS3(BuildProcess.java:325)
at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendS3Build(BuildProcess.java:386)
at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendRequestToServer(BuildProcess.java:459)
at com.codename1.build.client.CodeNameOneBuildTask.execute(CodeNameOneBuildTask.java:505)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor649.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

C:\Users\Javalove\Dropbox\MyDocs\MobileApps\CReporter\build.xml:343: Error in server build process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a VPN and the build was successful. I think its something with my ISP.

Answer (score 1):

The servers aren't down. This is a stage in the build where you connect to Amazon's S3 which is our least reliable build stage (take that serverless drones). Still S3 isn't down.

I'm guessing you're using an old version of JDK8 which had issues with some certificates. Make sure you're using a later release of that JDK and a reliable connection.

Comment: I have downloaded NetBeans 11 with the latest JDK 8 and I still have the same error. I am confused. This was working just fine the previous day..! Am i the only one experiencing this?